# PHP, how to check if a MySQL table has a name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to connect to the MySQL database to check a table (builditblocks) to see if there is data the user gave in the "name" column.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
 $temp=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `builditblocks`.`module_index`.`name`");
 $i = 0;
 while($module = mysqli_fetch_array($temp))
 {
   "moduleArray[".$i."]=\"" . $module["name"]."\";" ;
   $i++
   //stuck here I need to know how to
   //store them all in an array and check
   //to see if the input matches any array elements
 }
```

How do I check the table if it has the name?

Comment: that code doesnt look how it should. Heres a fiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/7xeBC/

Comment: Please format your code (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so it's easier to look at. Also, what you are asking is very basic, I would suggest reading a basic tutorial on SQL and PHP before posting.

Comment: I suggest you to filter your matches directly in SQL query by using WHERE statement. But first you need to sanitize user input at least by using `mysql_real_escape_query()` function. You should also look into PDO library rather than using outdated mysqli functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, push names to new array and check with `in_array`

```
$modules = array();
while($module = mysqli_fetch_array($temp))
{
   $modules[] = $module['name'];
}

if(in_array($_POST['input'], $modules))
    echo "I found";
else
    echo "Not found";
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the "WHERE" clause combined with "LIKE".

```
$temp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `builditblocks`.`module_index`.`name` WHERE `name` LIKE '%input%'");
```

The above code will give you only the records that contain "input" in their name.
Look http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To find if a name exists in your database, all you need to do is add a `WHERE` to your SQL query.

```
$name = $module['name'];

"SELECT * FROM 'builditblocks'.'module_index'.'name' WHERE name = '".$name."'"
```

Then check to see if that returns anything. If so, the name exists, if not then it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$name = $module["name"]; // Assign your user input to a variable
$temp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM builditblocks.module_index WHERE name = '" . $name . "'"; // Get all fields from table where the name field equals the user input.
if ($temp) {
    // If any records were returned the name exists
} else {
    // Otherwise the name doesn't exist
}
```

Hope this helps.